# How can I copy value only if another column says "Completed"?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

How can I copy value to another tab from column "price" in which I type price only if column "status" says "Completed"?

I have Appointments tab in which I type prices of my service and I write in status column "Completed" or "Pending"; now I have second tab called Income/Expenses in which I want to automatically copy values from "Price" column from "Appointments" tab but only if status column says "Completed".

Sorry if it's confusing, feel free to ask me more.

Comment: I've upvoted this not because the question is great, but because TheSparcy98 is new here, and they have made an attempt at reasonable question - ie this is not spam or particularly off-topic.

Comment: Here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fD_ELFD4sCjtdusuTd7YCxxoqfTuAfxUNM1mkgcTFXw/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Making us log in to Google and then request access just so we can help you is not cool.

Comment: Sorry if i did something wrong, im first time on this forum and new to sheets :/

Comment: Is this an Excel Spreadsheet or a Google One?  If its a Google one you should edit your tags - the microsoft-excel tags are incorrect as you are not using Excel.

Comment: Its google sheets, i thought they are using same formulas. I also put tag sheets as it doesnt allow me google tag. Im sorry for inconvenience once again, im super new to anything excell. Im still learning

Comment: I've updated your tags - I removed the Excel ones and found a "google-spreadsheets" one would seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.  You may want to provide a link to the spreadsheet or further details.   If my understanding of what you are trying to do is correct, and if the status COLUMN is Column C and the price is Column B you may be able to do something like

```
  =IF(OR($Appointments.C4="Completed";$Appointments.C4="Pending");$Appointments.B4;"")
```

Breaking this down -

$Appointments means the Tab called "Appointments"
$Appointments.C4 means the C4 tab in Appointments.
The OR function will return true if either of the conditions match
The IF Statement will return the results of B4 from the Appointments tab and the "" will return a blank.

I note that the code above is pretty generic and should work in any reasonable fully blown spreadsheet program.  (I use LibreOffice, but used Excel documentation to come up with it).  It is possible that Excel may correct it to be a slightly different form, but it should work just fine.

I believe I have actually done this for your spreadsheet using the following syntax (which would go in F4 and you could then copy and paste it for all rows)

```
   =if(or(Appointments!I6="Completed";Appointments!I6="Pending");Appointments!H6;"")
```

(Currently I've got it working in a new column F)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will provide more information. So i have 2 tabs, first one is called "Appointments", second one is called "Income/Expenses". In the first one i have column H called "Price" and column I called "Status". In "Income/Expenses" tab i have column C called Income in which when i type price in any row (for instance 70€) it automatically copies to "Income/Expenses" tab column C. Now i want it to copy ONLY if im "Appointments" tab column I says "Completed". Cause i put prices when i have appointments depending of what service customer wants and then i write Pending or Completed

Comment: Here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fD_ELFD4sCjtdusuTd7YCxxoqfTuAfxUNM1mkgcTFXw/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Have you actually tried applying an appropriately modified version of my If statement?

Comment: Thank you for help!! Problem solved